# Toggling Tabs and Spaces

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I work on different projects that have preferences for tabs and others for spaces. Is there a way to toggle using tabs or spaces for indentation? I tried a function I saw online `function TabToggle()` but it did not work. Any help would be great.

Comment: have a look at: https://github.com/tpope/vim-sleuth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally the `retab` command and the `expandtab` option can accomplish what you're talking about without plugins if that's what you want. Do `:set expandtab` to set vim to prefer spaces to tabs, `:set noexpandtab` to prefer tabs to spaces. Use `:retab!` to switch a whole file to whichever you've set. This has caveats, and I recommend [`:help :retab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#:retab) and [`:help 'expandtab'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27expandtab%27) for more information, and of course a plugin as already suggested will probably be more robust, but those settings are a quick-and-dirty way to get it done.

Comment: I like the use of this and can set mappings to this. The editorconfig works well but would probably prefer to stay with this option than having to rely on another plugin.

Answer (score 6):

I ***highly*** recommend [editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/).

Putting a very simple `.editorconfig` at the root of your project will make every IDE/editor with an editorconfig plugin automatically comply to the rules laid out in that config file. It's truly beautiful! No more mixed indentation!